# Division by zero checking

Tags: javascript, html, css

Doing my calculator...Want to check if my input str has "0" and if it is to alert error. But how not to check "/"? Here it is my function:

```
<input type="text"  name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkLength(this);" placeholder="Enter data" >

<input type="button" value=" &#247; " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '/';div(this);checkLength(this);" />

    function div(input) 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("t");
    var lastElement = (input.value.length-1);
    //alert(input.value.charAt(lastElement));
    if (input.value.charAt(lastElement) == 'null')
        { 
            alert(" / to Zero");
        }
}
```

Comment: Where/What is element `t`

Comment: Please post more code.  This is insufficient to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt` to evaluate the value of a string.

```
if (parseInt($("#myInput").val()) > 0) {
  // Do something...
}
```

You can also detect division by zero by using `isFinite`:

```
if (isFinite(1/0)) {
   // This won't run
} else {
   ...
}
```

`isFinite` will also return false for `NaN`:

```
if (isFinite(NaN)) {
   // This won't run
} else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
input.value.charAt(lastElement) == 'null'
```

in your if statement use

```
input.value[lastElement-1]+input.value[lastElement] === "/0"
```

This will check if the last section of the string is zero right after the `/` sign.

```js
function div(input) 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("t");
    var lastElement = (input.value.length-1);
    if (input.value[lastElement-1]+input.value[lastElement] === "/0")
        { 
            alert(" / to Zero");
        }
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  name="answer" id="t" placeholder="Enter data" >

<input type="button" value=" &#247; " onclick="div(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it is not full answer but what you can say about this one?

```
    function div(input) 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("t");
    var lastElement = (input.value.length-1);

    //alert(input.value[lastElement-1]);
    //alert(input.value[lastElement]);


    if (input.value[lastElement-1] === "/")
        { 
            if (input.value[lastElement] === "0")
            { 
            alert(" / to Zero");
            }
        }
}
```